# Can't add Unit Tests to existing iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I a trying to add Unit Test to an already working iOS App. I've searched and read many threads that address this problem, and followed their advices step-by-step but I seem to get stuck at a different place.

The app is an ordinary iPhone Application, that I am currently developing using Xcode 6.3.1 I've been able to create the 'Cocoa Touch Testing Bundle' fine for my Application. A basic test gets created, but when I press the 'Test' button, I get the message

> **Configure "Project Tests" for testing.**
>
> The scheme "Project Tests" is not configured for testing. Edit the scheme to enable testing, or cancel the action.

I press the 'Edit Scheme' button and go to the Edit Scheme Editor. But in that window (you can see a snapshot below this explanation) I am never able to choose any targets, all the options are actually greyed out! I've tried everything but I am not really sure what I should change in my project in order to change this and successfully create the Unit Tests... Any ideas please?

[image: Choose targets to test]

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Could you show your targets and schemes?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the process which i have followed to add the Unit testing in a demo projects. First of all i have deleted test scheme from the project which looks like this

[image]

Then i click on the plus icon which is located in the lower corner, then under ios section from other i have selected **Cocoa Touch Testing Bundle** like this

[image]

Then i have selected the **Language, Project and Target** as i have used in my project like this

[image]

After adding the test scheme in my project, i go to Edit Scheme and selected Test from there like this

[image]

Then i selected the Plus button to add the newly created Test scheme to my project like this

[image]

From there i have selected the Scheme and see in the below screenshot, the scheme is added to my project

[image]

Then is selected to test the app and see in the below screenshot i am able to test my app

[image]

Try to do this.I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Rajatp, thank you for your help! I am doing the steps you mention, but I get stuck in the step where you say "Then i selected the Plus button to add the newly created Test scheme to my project like this". For some reason, I am not able to choose the newly created Test Scheme. It appears there, but I am not allowed to select it!

Comment: Hello Ignacio Oroná, will you give me the screenshot of that screen.

Comment: Hi Rajatp, The screenshot is the same that I added in my original question. My screen shot would match the fifth screen that you've gently uploaded. But in my case I am not able to select anything! Thxs in advance

Comment: I think you are messing something in your target.Have you tried after removing your previously added Test setup.

Answer (score 8):

I think your issue is that you have created a new scheme for the test bundle. Try going to the scheme that you are using to run your app and selecting 'Edit Scheme'. Click on 'Test' and click the plus in the lower left corner. You should then be able to select your test bundle there. When you press the 'Test' button on your app scheme now it should run the test bundle.

From your screenshot above it looks like you have a scheme for your testing bundle, which shouldn't be the case. If you do have a scheme for your testing bundle you should remove it and start from the very beginning. I created a new project that only have the 'Test' scheme to make an example with only one scheme.

[image]

Click on your project from the Project navigator, the click the plus in the bottom right to add a new testing bundle.

[image]

Make sure that the target to be tested is your project, otherwise, I think you may end up in the situation you described above.

[image]

Now, when you select the scheme that you are using to run your app you should see the new testing bundle under the 'Test' section.

[image]

Comment: Hi @jhildensperger tried what you mentioned, but same exact result. I get to the same screen I added to the original questions with the same 2 options, 'proj' and OHAttributedLabel but none of them are grayed, and not choosable...

Comment: I added more of a walk-thru so hopefully that helps you out. If not and you can link to your project on github I could be more helpful.

Comment: In which step did it fail?